# Getting error while installing ReDash on my Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, root, redash

While running the bootstrap.sh file on root m getting this error (1st line in terminal) 404 not Found. I checked that URL it's not present actually. Here is the 
[Terminal screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCofn.png) I wanted to install Redash on my ubuntu, what will i do